# Download folder from Amazon S3 bucket using .net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to download entire folder present inside s3 bucket using .net sdk.Tried with below code, it throws invalid key.I need to download all files present inside nested pesudo folder present inside bucket and removing file download limitations to 1000 which is default.

```
public static void DownloadFile()
{
var client = new AmazonS3Client(keyId, keySecret, bucketRegion);
        ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
        {
            BucketName = bucketName + "/private/TargetFolder",         
            MaxKeys = 1000
        };
        try
        {
            ListObjectsV2Response bucketResponse = client.ListObjectsV2(request);
            foreach (S3Object o in bucketResponse.S3Objects)
            {
                var getRequest = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketResponse.Name + "/private/TargetFolder",
                    Key = bucketResponse.Name +"/private/TargetFolder/"+ o.Key
                };
                var response = client.GetObject(getRequest);
                response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(downloadLocation + "\\" + o.Key);
                var responseCode = response.HttpStatusCode;
                if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Success downloaded : {o.Key}");
                }
                else if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Request Timeout error.");
                }
                else if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service Unavailable.");
                }
                else if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Internal Server error.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(amazonS3Exception.Message);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line of code gives you error?

Comment: While building ListObjectsV2Request object having bucketName BucketName = bucketName + "/private/TargetFolder"

Comment: instead of `bucketName + "/private/TargetFolder"` you need to use only `bucketName` for `ListObjectsV2Request` object creation.

Comment: Now it throws error inside getRequest Object since it loops through all the files present directly inside bucket but when it tries to find the same file with bucketname/folderpath/file it will throws error "Specified key not found" which is correct error since the same file does not exists inside the nested folder

Comment: So you need to debug your code and check what value you are getting in `o.Key` when you looping thru `bucketResponse.S3Objects`. Instead of doing `client.GetObject` you should first do `Console.WriteLine(o.Key);` so that you know what you are getting back `bucketResponse.S3Objects`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are always getting 0 in *S3Objects.Count*, try without using *Delimiter* property:

```
public async Task DownloadDirectoryAsync()
{
    var bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast2;
    var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, bucketRegion);

    var bucketName = "bucketName";
    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Prefix = "directorey/",
        MaxKeys = 1000
    };

    var response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
    var utility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
    var downloadPath = "c:\\your_folder";
    foreach (var obj in response.S3Objects)
    {
        utility.Download($"{downloadPath}\\{obj.Key}", bucketName, obj.Key);
    }
}
```

And of course, you need *s3:ListBucket* permission

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me

```
public static void DownloadFile()
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            var client = new AmazonS3Client(keyId, keySecret, bucketRegion);
            ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();

            request.BucketName = "BUCKET_NAME";
            request.Prefix = "private/TargetFolder";
            request.Delimiter = "/";
            request.MaxKeys = 1000;

            ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);
            var x = response.S3Objects;

            foreach (var objt in x)
            {
                GetObjectRequest request1 = new GetObjectRequest();
                request1.BucketName = "BUCKET_NAME";
                request1.Key = objt.Key;

                GetObjectResponse Response = client.GetObject(request1);
if(objt.Size > 0){
                using (Stream responseStream = Response.ResponseStream)
                {
                    Response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(downloadLocation + "\\" + objt.Key);
                }
}
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried with prefix and delimiter while building ListObjectsV2Response but it don't download the filed from "target folder" even if there are files in it.response.S3Objects.Count is always 0

Answer (score 0):

The solution marked as accepted uses client.ListObjects(request) which says on the descrition that will only take a max of 1000 files, if there are more files on the folder maybe the code below will work. Thanks.

```
    public void DownloadallBucketFiles(string bucketName, string folderPath = 
    null)
    {
         var bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
         var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(S3CredentialsKey, 
         S3CredentialsSecret);
         var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, bucketRegion);     

         var utility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
         var dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName);
         var filesInBucket = dir.EnumerateFiles()?.ToList();
         var path = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath)) ? S3LocalTempDir : 
         folderPath;

         if (filesInBucket == null)
             return;

         filesInBucket.ForEach(file =>
         {
             try
             {
                  if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, file.Name)))
                     utility.Download($"{path}\\{file.Name}", bucketName, 
                     file.Name);

                  Console.WriteLine(file.Name + " Processed");
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(file.Name + $" download failed with error: 
                  {ex.Message}");
             }
         });
     }
  }
```