# Use AWS SDK Amplify to download folder in S3

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm using amplify to download the folder in S3 but as I see it just provide me method to download a single file not the whole folder like .NET SDK (DownloadDirectoryAsync). Do anyone have the way to do it (or workaround).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you simply do a `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name ./local-folder`, do you need to download programatically?

Comment: thanks I will tried

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the objects and then download one by one.

[Download folder from Amazon S3 bucket using .net SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718196/download-folder-from-amazon-s3-bucket-using-net-sdk)

if its a one time thing, you could use cli
`aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name` ./local-folder`

Comment: here is a dot.net solution

Comment: you can easily port it to nodejs solution. if you want to download multiple files in the browser, you will need to write a server side api to serve multiple files as zip for the front end to download.